# Mysql error 1064, granting privileges

Tags: mysql, permissions

I'm trying to add privileges for a newly created user in my database (CLI). But i am getting an error, probably because i have a dash in my db name but how do you work around it?

Error:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
    near '-acc.* TO 'bivv-acc'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

The actual command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bivv-acc.* TO 'bivv-acc'@'localhost';
```

Note: I am in my database, not in the overview of all the databases. Any clues?

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to escape dash using the backticks like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bivv-acc`.* TO 'bivv-acc'@'localhost';
```

Check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) which says:

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word,
>   you must quote it whenever you refer to it.
>
> ...
>
> **The identifier quote character is the backtick ("`")**